# why isnt this padding working?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I created a drop down menu and works fine except I cant seem to be able to add padding to the submenu, I'm trying to add it to the inner most li element but it's not working for some reason. I have tried adding padding to the ul and li and neither work. Does anyone know what the issue is, that I'm missing?

https://jsfiddle.net/x0L1o242/28/

```
#mainMenu{
    display: flex;

}
li{
   list-style-type: none;
}
.dropDownMenu{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
}
.dropDwonMenu li{
    padding: 30px;//part that isnt working
}
.dropDownMenu ul{
     position: absolute;
     top: 30px;
     left:0px;
     visibility: hidden;
     background-color: lightblue;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 0;
}

.dropDownMenu:hover ul{
      visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: because of your typo ".dropDwonMenu li"

Comment: It's because you spelt `dropDownMenu` wrong for the li

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You typo'd dropDownMenu in your css.

Original

```
.dropDwonMenu li{
    padding: 30px;//part that isnt working
}
```

This one works

```
.dropDownMenu li{
    padding: 30px;//part that isnt working
}
```

Comment: thanks I apprecate it lesson learned dont code and post on stack over flow when half asleep lol

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try This Css

#mainMenu{
  display: flex;

}
li{
  list-style-type: none;
}
.dropDownMenu{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
}


.dropDownMenu li {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100px;
}
.dropDownMenu ul{
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left:0px;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}

.dropDownMenu:hover ul{
  visibility: visible;
}
```